# 4-digits login to Mac like Windows 8

Tags: login

I'm looking for an option or way to log into my Mac using just 4 digits (just like Windows 8/10) instead of using my very long iCloud password.

Answer (score 8):

From - **[How to Stop Using an iCloud Password to Login to a Mac](http://osxdaily.com/2015/05/23/stop-using-icloud-password-mac-login/)**

> 1. Go to the  Apple menu and choose “System Preferences”
> 2. Choose “Users & Groups” and select the primary Mac login that you want to disassociate the iCloud password and use a unique separate password for
> 3. Click the “Change Password” button next to the user name
> 4. At the prompt “Do you want to change your iCloud password, or stop using your iCloud password to unlock this Mac and create a separate password?” – choose “Use Separate Password…”
> 5. Set and confirm the new password and close out of System Preferences when finished